# Handle Vue Route on Page Reload from MVC Controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vue.js

Have a VUE SPA which is rendered from index.cshtml. i have an issue in which when users reload the page its is going to 404 page. how do i handle vue route from my mvc application.

Answer (score 0):

I think this article can help you to combine spa with .net MVC:

https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2017/aug/07/handling-html5-client-route-fallbacks-in-aspnet-core